# How do I assign Id to Dynamically Created HTML Table?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a HTML table dynamically. I am also trying to assign that table an 'id'. But after assigning the Id when i try to do `getElementById` i am getting `null`.

```
var table = document.createElement("TABLE");

table.id = "tblCopy";

document.getElementById("tblCopy");
```

Last line returning 'null'.

Answer (score 2):

You may have created a HTML element, but you never attached it to your page. This is why it's not indexable.

Try this:

```
var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
table.id = "tblCopy";
document.body.appendChild(table);
document.getElementById("tblCopy");
```

Comment: Thanks Devon Bernard, 
I think need to make my DOM concepts clear :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var table=document.createElement("table")

table.id="tblCopy"

document.body.appendChild(table);

document.getElementById("tblCopy");
```

All your code is right but without adding element to the body of document.You cannot access it.